# DrillDown Column chart to Stacked Column chart in Highcharts using Angular 5

Tags: highcharts, angular5, drilldown

I need to drilldown from a single series Column chart to stacked column chart (using Highcharts) in Angular 5, is there any example/demo?

**component.ts**

```
this.chart41 = new Chart({


                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category'
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
                },

                series: [
                    {
                        name: "Days",
                        // colorByPoint: true,
                        data: [
                            {
                                name: "6-May",
                                y: 62.74,
                                drilldown: "6-May"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "7-May",
                                y: 10.57,
                                drilldown: "7-May"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "8-May",
                                y: 7.23,
                                drilldown: "8-May"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "9-May",
                                y: 5.58,
                                drilldown: "6-May"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "10-May",
                                y: 4.02,
                                drilldown: "10-May"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "11-May",
                                y: 1.92,
                                drilldown: "11-May"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "12-May",
                                y: 7.62,
                                drilldown: "12-May"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                drilldown: {

                    series: [
                        {
                            name: "6-May",
                            id: "6-May",
                            data: [
                                [
                                    "P1",
                                    12
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P2",
                                    12
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P3",
                                    12
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P4",
                                    12
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "7-May",
                            id: "7-May",
                            data: [
                                [
                                    "P1",
                                    0.1
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P2",
                                    1.3
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P3",
                                    53.02
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P4",
                                    1.4
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "8-May",
                            id: "8-May",
                            data: [
                                [
                                    "P1",
                                    0.1
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P2",
                                    1.3
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P3",
                                    53.02
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P4",
                                    1.4
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "9-May",
                            id: "9-May",
                            data: [
                                [
                                    "P1",
                                    0.1
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P2",
                                    1.3
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P3",
                                    53.02
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P4",
                                    1.4
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "10-May",
                            id: "10-May",
                            data: [
                                [
                                    "P1",
                                    0.1
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P2",
                                    1.3
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P3",
                                    53.02
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P4",
                                    1.4
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "11-May",
                            id: "11-May",
                            data: [
                                [
                                    "P1",
                                    0.1
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P2",
                                    1.3
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P3",
                                    53.02
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P4",
                                    1.4
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "12-May",
                            id: "12-May",
                            data: [
                                [
                                    "P1",
                                    0.1
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P2",
                                    1.3
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P3",
                                    53.02
                                ],
                                [
                                    "P4",
                                    1.4
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
```

The view is something like this - 
[image]

On clicking on any column(say 6-May), it shows the drill-down of column chart for 6-May -

[image]

I want to show a **stacked column chart** in the drilled down chart (as of now there is only legend i.e 6-May).

Comment: I found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnthv74t/), but not able to run it in Angular 5

Comment: Here's a simple demo (click on `6-May` column): http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4hun98sw/ Notice that columns are stacked only if they've the same x coordinate.